# Add logout link to WordPress admin dashboard left sidebar menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add logout link(button) in the left side of my wordpress admin dashboard. Like on the picture.. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: What have you done ? Please take look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think it is a right question. I found some information about add_menu_page(); but  I want to add logout link not a page . This logout button isn't real,  I just wanna to move sign out (logout) from top right dashboard dropdown menu to my left side admin dashboard menu like on the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

> You can achive this using `admin_init` action hook and `global $menu`.

Here is this code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'text_domain_logout_link');

function text_domain_logout_link() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[9999] = array(__('Logout'), 'manage_options', wp_logout_url());
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

---

References:

- [admin_init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)
- [global $menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Admin_Globals)
- [Customizing Your WordPress Admin](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-your-wordpress-admin--wp-24941)

Comment: Perfect! It works but debugger shows me this :


Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /home/usr/public_html/folder/wp-admin/includes/menu.php on line 309

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /home/usr/public_html/folder/wp-admin/includes/menu.php on line 329

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /home/usr/public_html/folder/wp-admin/includes/menu.php on line 224

How can I solve it?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!! It works perfectly! Is there a way to add some dashicon to this link? ^^

Comment: I'm still struggling to the icon. :(

Comment: (((( Thanks Raunak^

Answer (score 0):

Use  following code

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');
 function register_custom_menu_page() {
            add_menu_page( 'admin_menu', 'Logout', '0', 'logout', 'users_add_login_logout_link'); 
        }
        function users_add_login_logout_link(){ ?>
                      <div id="dashboard" class="wrap">
                <div style="float: left; height: 48px margin: 7px 8px 0 0; width: 48px;">
                    <br>
                </div>
                <h2>Log Out</h2>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="put you image link" width="128px" height="128px" /></div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">Please wait we are logging you out ...</div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div style="padding: 10px 0; font-size: 25px;"><p>

            </div>
            <?php 
            $location = '"Location: ' . wp_logout_url() . '"';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; url=' . wp_logout_url(home_url()) . '"/>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, with a dashicon. Based on this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117078/wp-redirect-not-working-on-admin-menu-page).

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'logout_menu_item');
function logout_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page('', 'Logout', 'manage_options', 'logout', '__return_false', 'dashicons-external', 999); 
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'redirect_loggingout');
    function redirect_loggingout() {
    if ( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'logout' ) {
      wp_redirect( wp_logout_url() );
      exit();
    }
}
```