# WordPress admin menu: custom logout link shows as submenu item instead of menu item

Tags: wordpress

I added a custom logout link to my WP admin menu, but instead of appearing as a top-level menu item, it is displayed as a submenu item (smaller font size, left padding). The link itself works perfectly though. Any ideas how the code can be changed? Thanks!

[current admin menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrDqh.png)

The code I use is from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806222/add-logout-link-to-wordpress-admin-dashboard-left-sidebar-menu).

```
add_action('admin_init', 'text_domain_logout_link');


function text_domain_logout_link() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[9999] = array(__('Logout'), 'manage_options', wp_logout_url());
}
```

Comment: Are you using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/

Comment: No, I don't. This code is for my own plugin :)

Comment: Can u set style margin:0 and padding:0; in ul and li tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'text_domain_logout_link');
function text_domain_logout_link() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[9999] = array(__('Logout'), 'manage_options', wp_logout_url());
}
```

Tested and works on my wordpress

[image]

Updated:
If you want to show it to top-level then use this code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'text_domain_logout_link');
function text_domain_logout_link() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[9999] = array(__('Logout'), 'manage_options', wp_logout_url());

    // add class
    $menu[9999][4] =  "menu-top toplevel_page_menu";

    // Add Icon
    $menu[9999][6] =  "dashicons-update";

}
```

So it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Also in your wordpress it shows as a submenu entry (you can tell as the font size is smaller and it's not exactly left-aligned to the other menu entries). That's exactly the issue I try to solve :(